# Reset Windows Password with Ubuntu Live CD

Tags: password-recovery, live-environment

A friend brought me his PC with Windows Vista to reset the user password because he didn't use it for a long while and forgot his password.

So I found a tutorial on how to reset the password by using a Ubuntu Live CD and the software chntpw.

After I installed this software I mounted the SYSTEM partition by opening it with the file explorer. It is now available at /media/SYSTEM/

The tutorial says I have to open the file /windows/system32/config/sam with chntpw and reset the password with

```
chntpw -u USERNAME sam
```

After I did this it didn't show me any errors. So I unmounted the partition and rebooted the PC with the installed Windows Vista.
It is still locked with the old password.

Did I do any mistakes or is there an other way to reset the password?

Comment: Also, what about the SYSKEY thing? - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Accounts_Manager

Comment: Is there a reason for not doing this in Windows Vista? http://www.top-password.com/knowledge/reset-windows-vista-password.html Feels to me you are using the wrong tool for this job and that this should be done from within Windows or with Windows.

Comment: @Rinzwind those are windows guys...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You mustn't change the password with `chntpw`**, what you can do is reset it (if you could change it that means that you can read the previous password). The correct way to use it is:

```
cd /media/B830C9BC30C981BC/WINDOWS/system32/config
sudo chntpw SAM SECURITY
```

(change `B830C9BC30C981BC` as appropiated)

Once in this screen you will get to answer several questions. **READ CAREFULLY**. Select the account you want to modify then reset the password.

```
1 - Clear (blank) user password
2 - Edit (set new) user password (careful with this on XP or Vista)
```

If reseting the password directly doesn't work, you can activate the Administrator account and from there reset your password.

Comment: I cant find `B830C9BC30C981BC` in media.. what am I missing

Comment: You have to change B830C9BC30C981BC with your path that links to the Windows partition.

Comment: I have activated the administrator account( 1- clear (blank) didnt work for me) but how do I reset the password of my account from administrator account ?