# Removing Windows 8 SysKey encryption password

Tags: windows-8

I've been trying to achieve this for a while now: http://computernetworkingnotes.com/xp-tips-and-trick/remove-administrator-password.html

However i am running windows 8, and i'm not sure this would work. Can i use Ubuntu to fix.

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reset Windows Password with Ubuntu Live CD](http://askubuntu.com/questions/381639/reset-windows-password-with-ubuntu-live-cd)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Ubuntu.

First you need to install chntpw, in a terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get install chntpw
```

Once Ubuntu is loaded, mount your windows partition (usually it will auto mount if you are in a file manager and click on it's icon).
The newly mounted drive will likely be mounted to a point with the following path:

```
/media/<your user name>/<your drives name>
```

In a terminal use the `cd` command to navigate tot the above directory and then `cd` again to navigate to

```
Windows/System32/config
```

Now run:

```
sudo chntpw -l SAM
```

Comment: Can you please guide me further with the steps as i am new ubuntu user. Where do i type this: sudo apt-get install chntpw? I can't boot windows on my PC. Do i download ubuntu in my USB/CD, then run ubuntu and type it?
thanks

Comment: While it's tempting to tell you to download and install Ubuntu because it's, well, Amazing, and most people like it much better than Windows 8.  In reality you can just download and make a GNU/Linux cd with chntpw already installed such as Knoppix or linux.  How to make a bootable USB / CD / DVD is a different question that has been written about extensively and can be easily searched for.

Comment: Right! I just figured that out! I'm actually stuck where i have to mount my partition/OS drive.cd /media/disk/WINDOWS/system32/config/

Comment: lucky for you I was just editing that part of my answer ;-)

Comment: Right! I just figured that out! But i can't seem to mount my drive. tried different variations of /media..etc but always get the same message

Comment: if you open the file manager (I use kubuntu, so I'm not exactly sure which one is used in Unity, but I believe it's called nautilus ) on the left hand side the should be a drive icon, if you click on it, then Ubuntu should auto mount that drive for you.

Comment: It said unable to access "OS". Error mounting /dev/sda5 at media/ubuntu/OS..etc The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state.Please resume and shutdown windows fully….:(. Guess i'm out of luck

Comment: Your not totally out of luck, it can be fixed.  You should however google "NTFS partition is in an unsafe state"

Answer (score 0):

I've similiar suggestion,you can use what called NTPasswd.it's linux based and it's small only around 3 MB.Make a booatble flashdisk with it and you can remove any user or admin password in any Windows

Comment: This is the software included in my initial message. I tried booting it but it does not retrieve and partition. I can't seem to go further.

Comment: What i really do are (you'll need Windows where you can run Apps with admin privileages)

1-Download it from the real source

2-Extract it to the bootable FD

3-Using CMD with Admin priv. `j:\syslinux.exe -ma j:` (let say J: is your flashdisk path)

4-Unplug the USB then boot it up